# I'm making a horizontal touch-controlled carousel; should each slide move with or away from my finger?

Tags: website-design, web-app, touch-screen

My carousel is just a generic rectangle with multiple slides which loop around:

```
---- | --------- | ---       /* Where | is the page boundary and the boxes make up slides
 3  ¦|¦    1    ¦|¦  2         * 1, 2 and 3, which loop around as displayed.
---- | --------- | ---        */
```

Now I'm well aware that when sliding your finger across a touch screen the content will move with your finger, however I'm curious if this still applies when dealing with features like carousels, or whether it even greatly matters if this action is reversed.

Would it be poor user experience if rather than moving with my finger, the slides moved the opposite way?

```
  ---|-----  ---|-----
 ¦   |1  <----  |2    ¦
  ---|-----  ---|-----
    --- Swipe --->
```

Comment: well done for looking to design a carousel that responds to user action ... you might want to search UX.stackexchange for plenty of other info about carousels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interaction for touch screen finger swipes is for the background to move with the finger. This applies to swipes that move content, such as scrolling down a page of text, or when pinching to zoom, where the page moves simultaneously with the fingers as they move apart or together, or when repositioning an element, when it appears to stick with the finger.

Not only that, but the same applies to desktop interfaces that use mice, for example, google maps.

By reversing this you would be breaking interface consistency and a very well established touch-screen design pattern. You would end up with a situation where all elements responded in one way while your carousel would behave in the opposite way. I would not advise it.